# Unable to login in cypress tests (500 error)

Tags: cypress, e2e-testing

I was writing some E2E tests and suddenly all my tests started failing at the cy.request in login.

I have no idea why it started happening. It works fine for other colleagues.

I tried to fix it by clearing cache, clearing cookies, clearing localstorage, using npm ci, restarting the computer but nothing helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the issue is caused by a cookie that is set for the tests. Not sure how to fix it tho since we need the cookie inside the tests...

Answer (score 0):

500 status codes are associated with server issues.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/500

Maybe there was something deployed and made it break.

Comment: No, there is nothing wrong with the server. As I said I'm the only one having the issues and all of us tried running the same code. The tests are passing in the CI/CD aswel. The problem has to be in my laptop.